# syntax error near unexpected token `>' in script run by cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, cron

I'm writing a shell script for Mac OS/Linux. The script is run by a cron job. I'm trying to **append stdout and stderr** to a log file. My command(simplified) looks like this(line 5 in `myscript.sh`):

```
mycommand &>> log.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
myscript.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `>
```

However if I change the command to:

```
mycommand &> log.txt
```

I don't get any errors, but the file is overwritten (not appended).

Any idea why `&>>` doesn't work but `&>` works?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the command I showed is in line 5 in myscript.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cron` is executed using `sh` and the redirection syntax you are attempting to use is a Bash extension (and a fairly recent one at that; older versions of Bash only supported `&>`).

The portable way to append standard output and standard error to a file is

```
mycommand >>log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: excellent, this works and also explains the behaviour!